# How to seed db with exact same order?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

i've got EF code first project and seed method

```
situation2_1.RightActions.Add(new RightAction { ControlName = "HV1226-1", RightState = State.Off });
situation2_1.RightActions.Add(new RightAction { ControlName = "HV1227-1", RightState = State.Off });
situation2_1.RightActions.Add(new RightAction { ControlName = "HV2905-10", RightState = State.Off });
situation2_1.RightActions.Add(new RightAction { ControlName = "FV1010-1", RightState = State.Off });
situation2_1.RightActions.Add(new RightAction { ControlName = "FV1026-1", RightState = State.Off });
situation2_1.RightActions.Add(new RightAction { ControlName = "FV1415-1", RightState = State.Off });
```

After seeding database records are not in the same order as in the code
How to workaround this situation?

Comment: how do you determine that the records are not "in the same order". What is the problem? how are you retrieving the records? Can you not simply do an `order by`?

Answer (score 3):

The "order" of database records is undefined by design. The only order you can rely on is the order imposed by `ORDER BY` clause in `SELECT` statement.

This means that if for some reason you need to get the records from DB in exact order, you'll have to impose it explicitly.